# Blue screen crash causes my pc to slow down to death, not working anymore

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, bsod, bootloader, mbr

Three days ago, I was using BlueStacks. At that time, my PC fan went loud and I could notice for few seconds high CPU usage. There was no other program running at that time. I suddenly ran into the Blue Screen error saying that my device has encountered an issue and must be restarted. I had to restart it per error message, and when I restarted it, the Preparing Automaic repair message has been showing since then. This issue takes me 1 hour just to reach the the Preparing Automatic Repair message at the start up.

So, now I can't access my computer anymore.

I am now suspecting that MBR is corrupted! Not sure though about that.

Any idea where to start fixing my PC?

Comment: Boot from a Windows OS cd and go to repair option and select troubleshoot and select refresh option. This will refresh you OS.

Comment: if you get a preparing automatic repair option, the MBR isn't corrupt. Sounds like some important boot file is though. How bluestacks would do this, i have no idea. Whatever the case, vembutech's seggustion is a good one

Comment: would I loss my data if I did that? I have a lot of important files and documents over there...

Comment: By the way, I tried to boot from USB and took me forever to reach the advanced options page!

Comment: "This issue takes me 1 hour just to reach the the Preparing Automatic Repair message at the start up."  I don't understand that.  What happens during that hour?  Does your computer consistently reach "the Preparing Automatic Repair message" after time, or are you getting different results sometimes?

Comment: That's correct. Everytime I restart my PC it takes time to reach Preparing automatic repair screen. After that it goes black... nothing else.